# python xpath relative path get <p> before <br>

Tags: python, xpath

HTML:

```
<td>
    <p>China's Changing Trade Structure and its Implications
       <br>
       Kevin Chow, Xiao Hong, John Fu and Sylvia Li
    </p>
    <p>25 August 2017
        <br>
        <a href="/media/eng/publication-and-research/research/research-memorandums/2017/RM13-2017.pdf" target="_blank">Full Paper</a> 
        (PDF File, 465KB)
    </p>
</td>
```

I have obtained "a" shown in the picture and trying to get the title: "China's Changing Trade Structure and its Implications" and date: "25 August 2017" separately using a relative path from "a". But I can't get them. Here is the code:

```
for a in response.xpath('//div[@class="prContent"]//a[@href]'):
        url = response.urljoin(a.xpath('@href').extract_first())
        title = extract_text(a.xpath('../../p[1]/text()[1]'))
```

Comment: Share HTML as text, not as image

Comment: you need to share the parent of p and td tag and as Andresson said paste your code not image

Comment: http://www.hkma.gov.hk/eng/publications-and-research/research/research-memorandums/2017.shtml

Comment: This is the link. I can't copy the html text due to some reason.. sorry

Answer (score 1):

You can try below expressions to get required output:

1. To get `"China's Changing Trade Structure and its Implications"`:

   ```
   ../../p[1]/text()[1]
   ```
2. To get `"25 August 2017"`:

   ```
   ../../p[2]/text()[1]
   ```

P.S. This should work only if you correctly defined the link (`a`)

Comment: I tried but it didn't work. I just updated and included my code for "a". Could you take a look? Thx!

Comment: Do you use `lxml` for parsing? Did you get any exception with your code? `for a in response.xpath('//div[@class="prContent"]//a[@href]'): title = a.xpath('../../p[1]/text()[1]')[0]` works fine for me...